# Is there a way to sort splitted arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have three arrays of Integers (`arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`) storing in three different databases (`db1.table`, `db2.table`, `db3.table`). I can't retrieve the whole arrays from the tables because they just too large to store it into memory.

I need to get all sorted data from the whole array (union of the arrays) sorted in ascending order from `10*n` to `10*(n+1)` indexes where `n >= 0`. I can't retrieve the whole arrays, find their union and sort it. But I can retrieve sorted data in ascending order from `10*n` to `10*(n+1)` for any of this arrays.

```
arr1        arr2           arr3
 2           5              2
 43          2              234
 234         2              235
 23          5              234
 2           10             46
 1           17             456
 423        233             6
 2          422             46
 54         23              345
 ...............................
```

Is there an algorithm for that better than stupid search through all arrays?

Comment: Can't you just merge the results of the lookups on the individual arrays?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's the main difficulty. I just can't imagine how  I can merge them in a right way. Suppose I need to get 100--110 elements from the sorted array. Even If I get 100--110 elemts from any of the three arrays I can't just merge the results, sort them and say: Here's the set of elements containgn the result I need.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding then, because from reading your question, that sounds like exactly what you want!

Comment: Oh, you want that range of indices as measured in the *total* array?  If so, then I don't think there's a smart way of achieving this, other than streaming all the results, merging as you go, and then selecting the relevant sub-range.  If you're performing many such queries, there may be some sort of indexing you could construct.

Comment: Do you need to get elements 100 to 110 from each of the lists and then sort that (the result being a list of 30 elements) or you need to do the union and sort of the lists and then take elements 100 to 110 (10 elements) from the resulting list?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, I need to sort the whole array without explicitly storing it into a memroy.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You said that it's likely that there is more-or-less smart algorithm for that. So, if we have an array that's splitted across some data storage, we can't sort it efficiently till we explicitly find store the __total__ array somewhere, right?

Comment: @palako the _union_ is the thing that I need to avoid, because it'll take too much space and time to find it even if I want to store it in a separate table.

Comment: @St.Antario: I'm saying there is *no* smart algorithm for this.  The problem is that your result potentially depends on examining *all* (or most) of the data.  You don't have to *store* the whole thing in memory simultaneously, but you will need to *process* an arbitrary amount of it.

Comment: ok, check the edit to my previous answer then and see if that helps, hope you can write the algorithm with those indications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a cross database union, most engines will allow you to do this if the databases are in the same node or cluster.

```
mysql> select * from test.nums;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    5 |
|    7 |
|    9 |
+------+
mysql> select * from test2.nums;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    2 |
|    4 |
|    6 |
|    8 |
+------+
mysql> select * from test.nums union select * from test2.nums order by num limit 3, 6;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
+------+
```

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, the way to do this in code is using Cursors and a three-way merge.

Assuming you can do a **"SELECT num from test.nums ORDER BY num"** and a different **"SELECT num from test2.nums ORDER BY NUM"** (and a third time), then you would have three cursors to iterate the result set in your code. Now this depends on the implementation of the driver connecting to the database, but a cursor will normally work with a sliding window managing the memory for you. This means you can transparently iterate your entire recordset, but only portions of it at a time are in memory.

Once you have the three cursors, start iterating the sorted lists of elements one at a time. If you remember the mergesort algorithm, this is like the merge stage of it, only with three lists instead of two.

The other thing you need to do while iterating your cursors is to simply ignore every element you would have added to your sorted merged array before position x*100, start adding from there, and break of your loop when you reach (x+1)*100